# Website Code Is Not Uploading Changes

Tags: html, css

I used the Chrome inspector to make sure that my CSS rules were not apparent. I have tried doing hard refreshes and emptying the caches to no avail. I also edited the CSS from the server to make sure that the changes were made.

Local Code:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
@media (max-width: 480px)
.send {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Live Code:

```
.send {
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #393939;
}
```

Why is the server displaying the wrong code?

EDIT: I have tried deleting all of my selectors for .send except for one. But when I upload the code to the server, it still displays old code

Code Displayed In Editor On Server:

```
.send { 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #393939;
}
```

Code Displayed In Inspector On Live Website:

```
.send {
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #393939;
}
```

Comment: Your media query is not complete. You need to enclose `.send` with media query.

Comment: I took out the media queries and used only one selector to make sure one rule wasn't overwriting the other. So now I have only one CSS rule for `.send` and it's not being updated on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries don't have any  selectors. Since they fail to work CSS engine doesn't show them in the inspector. However, if you  see the main CSS file the rules should be there. In fact your server doesn't know anything about CSS. It doesn't/shouldn't change your CSS files. Your CSS should be:

```
@media (max-width: 768px), (max-width: 480px) {
    .send {
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two css rules for `.send` and one rewrite another.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure that the element that has `.send` class is not overwritten by another, you can use `!important` to force the styling.

```
.send {
    width: 180px !important;
    background-color: #393939 !important;
}
```